# Get rid of page breaks in report

Tags: reporting-services, page-break

How do I get rid of the page breaks in an SSRS report, making  the report display in a single page?

Answer (score 57):

Open the report's .rdl file in a text editor and locate the `<Page></Page>` section.
In that section, insert the following:

```
<InteractiveHeight>0in</InteractiveHeight>
<InteractiveWidth>8.5in</InteractiveWidth>
```

In SSRS, an interactive height of 0 means the report has an infinite length and therefore, it will exist on a single page.

Comment: InteractiveHeight does not exist in new SSRS !

Answer (score 19):

Make sure you do not have one of the properties set to true on one of your report items for **PageBreakAtEnd** or **PageBreakAtStart**. Also, make sure you keep the width of your report less than the width of your actual paper, keeping in mind extra space for the page margins (Report > Report Properties > Layout)
And according to Microsoft:
"Although it is not recommended, you can disable soft page breaks by setting InteractiveHeight to 0." I think this only works for HTML rendering though, I have not used it myself. 
I'm not sure if there is a scale of any kind where no matter how big your report is it still prints on one page if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 14):

Right Click anywhere in Body and select `Properties`.

select `Reports` From the DropDown. (When you select an element in report, the dropdown changes to TextBox/Header or the item you select)

In `Report` properties, Expand `InteractiveSize` Attribute.

Set `Height -> 0in`

Comment: This may be for older versions of Visual Studio (or Report Builder?). In SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2015, @nccsbim071 's answer is what worked for me (the properties panel is a pane on the IDE that is always open rather than a dialog accessible from a context menu.)

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to display report data in one page, it is simple to do in SSRS.  All you have to do is select an entire table and then go to the property pane.  Update *KeepTogather = True*.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can set the report's InteractiveHeight to 0 to disable paging.

Go to report properties -> Page -> InteractiveSize -> Height. Set this value to 0in.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/6c240863-216b-4e6a-9c67-197d98b0f18c) is the similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Dustin Brooks wrote:

> Also, make sure you keep the width of your report less than the width of your actual paper, keeping in mind extra space for the page margins (Report > Report Properties > Layout)

Also be extra careful about this when working with subreports. I've lost count of the times I ended up with extra blank pages when I've accidently made a subreport wider than the main report.

Answer (score 1):

When creating reports for the web, I would disable page breaks by setting the InteractiveSize to something really crazy, like 1000x1000". (I just checked, and setting it to 0x0" as Dustin Brooks [mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461782/ssrs-report-get-rid-of-page-breaks-in-report/461854#461854) has the same effect.)

I left the PageSize property at 8.5x11" and the reports printed across multiple pages normally.