# Reporting Services 2008 - Long subreports cause page break

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

[Similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461782/ssrs-report-get-rid-of-page-breaks-in-report), but I have one "master" report which contains many subreports. Everything works great until one of the subreports, when rendered (to PDF, for example), will take up > the space left on a page.  In this case, the page breaks so that the subreport starts on a new page.  Sometimes this looks incredibly awkward when the one report only takes up a little bit of room on one page, then it breaks to the next page because the following subreport is too long.  Any suggestions?  It is not a width/margin problem, because when all of the subreports are short, it looks fine.  Also, I am using HTML placeholders, and I do not have any margins set on the subreports, nor do I have any of these checked:

- Add a page break before
- Add a page break after
- Keep contents on a single page, if possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the MS article [KB938943](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/938943), I was unable to fix this...

Comment: Crazy, so this is "by design?" I thought subreports were good for reusing different pieces across multiple reports...oh well.

Answer (score 2):

In Reporting Services 2008, there is a new property on the **Subreport** called **KeepTogether**. This was always True in 2005 with no way to change it. We've had great success in getting rid of blank space and blank pages in 2008 (with exception to dynamic height property on charts, but thats another ticket).

Also check for **KeepTogether** on your **grids**, **rectangles**, etc.. and turn them all to False when you don't want them to stay together.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any groupings in the subreports that specify page breaks? If so, this may cause the page break. regardless of the settings in the 'master' report.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case.